# Windows Update Error Code 80072EFE

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I have installed Windows Server 2012 R2 RTM. Now, in order to install SharePoint, seems like I will have to update the server upto April 2014 update. But no matter, whatever I do, I see the following error: 
[image]
Anyone who can help me on this? Need an urgent fix.

Comment: Great! Could you please let me know, what's the reason behind the upvote? Who knows? That might help me resolve the problem!!

Comment: Is your server a part of domain (AD)? How are updates deployed - online / WSUS / SCCM, etc.? Have you checked the firewall settings? Please provide the necessary information by editing in the question itself!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to time skew on the server, or possibly Windows Firewall getting in the way.

First, I would double check the server has the correct Time Zone, Date, and Time. (If you have trouble setting the time, and the server is a virtual machine, on the hypervisor side, disable clock syncing of the VM to the host hardware)

After rebooting the server, and it holds the correct date/time, then try the update again. If still no luck, you can easily disable the windows firewall with the below command in an administrator command prompt:

```
NetSh Advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

If needed, you can reenable the firewall with this similar command:

```
NetSh Advfirewall set allprofiles state on
```

Try the update again once you've disabled the Windows firewall

Bonus fun command to show the current status of the Windows firewall:

```
Netsh Advfirewall show allprofiles
```

Answer (score 0):

[That error code indicates the network connection was "terminated"](http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm).

> 0x80072EFE ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED   The connection with the server has been terminated.

Doesn't sound like an actual network issue, so I would advise trying to download and install the update manually from the [Microsoft Update Catalog site](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx).  It might work, or you might get a more useful error message about why the update can't be installed.

I've seen similar issues when a prerequisite update has been expired or superseded, or when the Windows Update client is out of date, so you might need to install other updates first.  It might also turn out that the specific update you're trying to install is itself superseded or expired, and you need a more recent patch instead of the one you're trying to install.  Either way, you should know more after you try manually installing the update in question.

Answer (score 0):

For this error on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2, [this is the fix](https://www.repairwin.com/fix-80072efe-update-error-in-windows-7/).  That is, install [KB3138612](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3138612).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community That is the whole fix.  Install KB3138612.  That's it.  And I referenced the article that says to do so.  And it worked.